# RabbitMQ channel lifetime and access in ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, thread-safety

I have a ASP NET Core application that will serve as a `RabbitMQ` producer.I have read the tutorial and guides regarding the `RabbitMQ .NET` client and i still do not know how to deal with the channel lifetime and concurrent access.
From what i have read i understood the following:

- `IConnection` is  threadsafe ,but is costly to create
- `IModel` is not threadsafe but is lightweight

For the `IConnection` i would initialize it in the `Startup` and inject it as a singleton (service).
However i I do not know how to deal with `IModel`  management.Lets say i have a couple of services that use it, is it scalable to just :

**Solution 1**

```
public void Publish(IConnection connection)
{
         using(IModel model=connection.CreateChannel())
         {
               model.BasicPublish(...);
         }
}
```

**Solution 2**

From what i  have read , i understood that its not really scalable.
So another solution would be to create a separate service which would contain a loop , a ConcurrentQueue, and all services would dispatch messages here.
This service would be the sole publisher to `RabbitMQ`

**Publisher**

```
public class Publisher
{
    private CancellationTokenSource tcs=new CancellationTokenSource();

    public BlockingCollection<byte[]> messages=new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

    private IModel channel;
    private readonly string ExchangeName;
    private Task loopTask;

    public void Run()
    {
          this.loopTask=Task.Run(()=>Loop(tcs.Token),tcs.Token);
    }
    private void Loop(Cancellation token)
    {
          while(true)
          {
             token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
             queue.Take(out byte[]data);
             channel.BasicPublish(...,body:data);
          }
    }
    public void Publish(byte[] message)
    {
       this.queue.Add(message);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class SomeDIService
{
    private IConnection connection;
    SomeDIService(Publisher publisher)
    {
       this.publisher=publisher;
    }
    public void DoSomething(byte[] data)
    {
           //do something...
          this.publisher.Publish(data);
     }
}
```

I would prefer solution 1 but i do not know the performance penalty ,while i do not like solution 2 since i wanted to just publish messages directly to `RabbitMQ`.Now i have to deal with this long running  `Task` too.
Is there any other solution , am i missing something ? Is there a simpler way?

**Update**

I mentioned concurrent access.I meant i need a way to publish messages from multiple endpoints (services) to RabbitMQ.

**Real scenario**

```
public class Controller1:Controller
{
    private SomeDIService service; //uses Publisher
    [HttpGet]
    public void Endpoint1()
    {
       this.service.DoSomething();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public void Endpoint2()
    {
       this.service.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Controller2:Controller
{
    private SomeDIService service;
    [HttpGet]
    public void Endpoint3()
    {
        this.service.DoSomething();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public void Endpoint4()
    {
        this.service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit more context would be helpful --- in particular, you state "concurrent access" does this mean you have multiple applications publishing? or does this particular application require concurrent publishing?

Comment: I need a way to publish messages to a target `exchange` with a `routingKey` throughout my application.That is why i do not know the best strategy.Use a special `thread` to queue messages and write them to `RabbitMQ`  usign a single `IModel` , or create a `IModel` for each publishing action.

Comment: Solution 2 is essentially a single instance of a background task that you can queue messages to and it looks "okay" to me. -- I would recommend staying away from `while(true)` -- probably going to see quite a bit of CPU use for no good reason. However, it's not clear of the advantage of Solution 1 as you are not showing the usage of it in your code (i.e. are you injecting it? how is it instantiated? etc)

Comment: I did not post the `Solution1` since it is trivial. I just spawn a `IModel` whenever i need to publish a message. It was a typo, instead of a `ConcurrentQueue` i changed it to `BlockingCollection` , so that `while(true)` becomes a non-issue.

Comment: I think the `ConcurrentQueue` was already a good choice for this, not sure about the benefits of the `BlockingCollection` in your use case. -- in any case, I'm not entirely sure how to help answer your question.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` would make sense from my point of view since i do not want to put arbitrary delays to throttle the loop.I posted the question since i was hoping someone already had to do this integration with `ASP NET Core` and had any tips/guidance or encountered issues that i don't foresee so far.

Answer (score 0):

after searching for long time i found this solution and it works very good for me

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BSG.MessageBroker.RabbitMQ
{
    public class Rabbit : IRabbit
    {
        

        private readonly EnvConfigModel EnvConfig;
        private readonly string _hostname;
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly string _exchangeName;
        private readonly string _username;
        private IConnection _connection;
        private IModel _Model;
        public Rabbit(IOptions<EnvConfigModel> appSettings)
        {
            EnvConfig = appSettings.Value;
            _Logger = services;
            _exchangeName = EnvConfig.Rabbit_ExchangeName;
            _hostname = EnvConfig.Rabbit_Host;
            _username = EnvConfig.Rabbit_Username;
            _password = EnvConfig.Rabbit_Password;

            CreateConnection();
            _Model = _connection.CreateModel();
        }

       
        private void CreateConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = _hostname,
                    UserName = _username,
                    Password = _password,
                    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
                    TopologyRecoveryEnabled = true,
                    NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                };
                _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not create connection: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        

        private bool ConnectionExists()
        {
            if (_connection != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            CreateShredderConnection();

            return _connection != null;
        }


      


        public bool PushToQueue(string Message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ConnectionExists())
                {
                        byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Message));

                        _Model.BasicPublish(exchange: _exchangeName,
                                         routingKey: 1001,
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: body);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```